# Django search_fields foreign key not working

Tags: django, django-admin

I have these two models :

```
class Module(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class Subject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
```

I then created ModelAdmin:

```
class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('module', 'name', 'enabled',)
    list_filter = ('module', 'name',)
    search_fields = ('module', 'name',)
```

But I cannot filter or search by module.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you register the ModelAdmin?

```
admin.site.register(Subject, SubjectAdmin)
```

You might also want to try either giving module a `__unicode__` method, or using relationship spanning.

```
list_filter = ('module__name', 'name',)

# or...
# within Module
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Yes I did register the subject model. It works with the code below.

I did try module_name before, now I know it is module__name.

Thanks.

Comment: Giving the module `__unicode__` is not enough to make search work. Even if you have this, you need `module__name` for the `search_fields` to work, as of Django 1.6.1

Answer (score 9):

For refrencing foreign key use __

Example if you want name of module:

```
class Module(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name:

class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('module', 'name', 'enabled',)
    list_filter = ('module__name', 'name',)
    search_fields = ('module__name', 'name',)
```